# MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: mysql

Ошибка в вопросе, я настраиваю, всё работает, после, если не было никаких обращений в продолжительный период и потом происходит обращение выводится данная ошибка, что с ней делать не понимаю, решений в интернете пока не нашел. Заранее благодарен за ответ. Конфиги по умолчанию, всё разворачиваю на докере ничего кроме как создание базы данных и разворачивания её через дамп с базой не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если соединение долгое время не используется, то сервер может его разорвать (зачем занимать ресурсы, если ничего не происходит). Время ожидания настраивается опцией [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) или [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout).

Решение на поверхности: в случае возникновения такой ошибки надо просто переподключиться к базе.

Comment: Да, это является решением, я использовал ОРМКУ которая как оказалось не закрывала коннекшин и не создавала его при новом клиенте, посему, всё падало. Решил это всё через пулинг.